# MySQL problem to find employee with highest CURRENT compensation

Tags: mysql, sql

Table: emp

```
---------------------------------
EID     | NAME      | TITLE
1       | Dee       | Director
2       | Mac       | Analyst
3       | Dennis    | Engineer
4       | Charlie   | Janitor
---------------------------------
```

Table: comp

```
-----------------------------------------
EID     | BEGIN_DT   | END_DT     | SALARY
1       | 2018-01-01 | 2018-02-01 | 100
1       | 2018-02-02 | 2018-03-15 | 110
1       | 2018-03-16 | 2018-03-31 | 130
1       | 2018-04-01 | 2019-12-31 | 120
-----------------------------------------
```

Question. Return the name and salary for the employee with the highest current compensation

Comment: Hello Siddhant Farwaha, welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far? You are supposed to show your effort, and explain where you got stucked.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is a little unclear on what exactly you'd be looking for, as well the comp table only has one employee on it so it would always be EID 1 or Dee. Not sure if this is a mistake or now.

Besides that, I think there are a few different ways of doing this. How I would do it would be to join the tables where the EID is equal to each other, order the table by the salary in ascending order, and then limit to 1. This should give you one record of who has the highest compensation.

However, this does not take into account the dates and stuff. The question is a little unclear. If you wanted something like that, then you'd but using a subquery to calculate the salary * date-difference then doing something similar to above.

Hope this gets you pointed into a better direction! Good luck!

Comment: This is an interview question which my friend could not solve. Maybe the interviewer provides some clarification as the question is being solved. 
I admit the question is a bit vague but I think it wants us to take the date in account to get the current compensation. Do you think the code below makes sense?


SELECT e.NAME, MAX(c.SALARY) FROM emp e
JOIN comp c on e.EID = c.EID
GROUP BY e.NAME
HAVING TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, C.END_DT, SYSDATE()) < 0;

The salary * date difference also makes sense.